# Using a varying DC voltage signal to trigger an on/off signal?

Tags: voltage, controller

This question is for automotive use.
A system monitors a constant voltage of 3.3 to 5 V (this voltage is fixed but varies from vehicle to vehicle) to indicate an "okay" status, when there is an issue the voltage drops to 1.3 - 2.6 V (not sure if the voltage varies as the issue grows).

Is there a way to monitor the 3.3 - 5 V signal and have it trigger a relay, switch, warning ... when the voltage drops to 2.6 V or lower without programming a controller?

Looked up color changing LED thinking perhaps they change color with voltage. They don't.
Looked for voltage adjustable relays but didn't find what I need.

The details:
I am running a car with a factory knock control system, it is still connected to the factory ECU.
The system consists of a "knock control unit" and a knock sensor.
The knock control unit receives +12 V and ground, it generates a 3.3 to 5 V signal and sends it to the knock sensor, it monitors the knock sensor voltage and sends it to the ECU. When the sensor detects knock and vibrates it creates resistance (I'm assuming) and puts out a lower voltage.
When the ECU receives a voltage of 2.6 V or lower it pulls ignition timing up to 6 degrees and reduces turbo boost.
The solenoid valve used to lower boost during knock was also used to lower boost at high rpm in every gear. The ecu uses a single pin signal to do this so there is no way to separate the unwanted rpm operation from the knock operation of the solenoid. Therefore the solenoid cannot be used.

Over the years I have looked in to independent knock control systems, audible knock listening devices, knock control on engine management...
But engine knock happens at different frequencies on different motors, the frequency often have to be dialed in, to set some devices up to prevent knock you must cause knock. The knock frequency for this engine is unknown.

The factory knock control unit and sensor are designed to pick up the right frequency for knock on this motor. I have many extra sensors and controllers.
If I install and wire a second independent knock sensor and knock controller I have the same voltage signal to work with that the ECU does.

How to convert that signal drop into an on/off signal?
Or how to use a change in signal voltage to trigger an event?
Monitoring the voltage on a gauge is not a practical option.

I am not afraid to do the ground work and research but this is not my realm of knowledge. All I have to work with is my imagination. Electronics is so vast I don't know what to look for.
Thought asking the experts would yield much better solutions than guessing and searching.

Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need a comparator, alternatively two of them to form a window comparator.

Comment: and possibly with the comparator output connected to a relay (preferably solid state relay these days) to have on/off control over something large.  Relay not necessary if simply lighting an LED.

Comment: Thank you Winny that is exactly what I need. Looking into them now. Don't think I ever would have stumble upon comparators.                                                     Thank you Ben Voigt that's exactly how I need to use it.

Comment: You might also want your circuit to exhibit *hysteresis*, i.e., to tend to remain in one state rather than flipping back-and-forth continually for very small voltage fluctuations. For example, once a low-voltage warning is shown, it should stay lit until the voltage rises a set amount.

Comment: any schmitt-trigger having IC will do what you ask, a hex inverter might be simplest since you can feed one output to another input input to re-invert and still have 4 left over.

Comment: Looking into all this stuff and learning it. Would hysteresis or Schmitt-trigger be necessary if I run a Beuler bu509td time delay off relay? They get triggered by a + dc signal and stay on from 2s to 3m adjustable. Has negative feedback protection.